# after changing theme for one Mailable file in laravel it messup other email which dont have $theme variable set

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8, laravel-blade

below is my code to change the theme for particular emails where TablerMailable is extended.

```
class TablerMailable extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Instruct to use tabler theme.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $theme = 'tabler';

    /**
     * Build the Markdown view for the message.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function buildMarkdownView()
    {
        $markdown = Container::getInstance()->make(Markdown::class);
        $markdown->loadComponentsFrom([resource_path('views/vendor/tabler-mail')]);

        if (isset($this->theme)) {
            $markdown->theme($this->theme);
        }
        
        $data = $this->buildViewData();

        $views= [
            'html' => $markdown->render($this->markdown, $data),
            'text' => $this->buildMarkdownText($markdown, $data),
        ];
        
        return $views;
    }
}
```

> this is my class which extends TablerMailable to send email from
> custom theme and custom views which are in /views/vendor/tabler-mail
> folders.

```
class DailyUpdate extends TablerMailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $user;
    
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
    
    public function build()
    {
      return $this->markdown('emails.marketing.daily-update-notification');
    }

}
```

this UserRegisterd class uses the Mailable class to send emails using the default theme and default views.

```
class UserRegisterd extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $user;
    
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
    
    public function build()
    {
      return $this->markdown('emails.new-users);
    }

}
```

DailyUpdate email goes daily at 8:00 Am using scheduler jobs
and new users' email when any user registered in the system.

now whenever the daily update email goes using a custom theme and views it also changes the theme for new user email too.

below is my markdown file

```
1. daily-update-notification.blade.php
   

@component('mail::message')
    <table class="box" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td class="py-lg border-bottom">
<table class="row row-flex" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td class="col text-mobile-center text-center">
<span class="font-strong">Daily Summary Report of {{ $user->name }}
for {{ $date->format('F jS,Y') }}</span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
@endcomponent



2. new-user.blade.php
@component('mail::message')
Hello {{ $user->first_name }},
Congratulation. You now have an account on {{ config('storat.APP_NAME') }}. The next step is to create a business account.
Thanks,<br>    
{{ config('storat.APP_NAME') }}
@endcomponent
```

Comment: We'll need more information to be able to help you. Show the code where the `TablerMailable` class is used and where it is not; show the expected and actual output of the mail messages you say are not correctly formatted; do the Mailable classes share the same view for rendering?

Comment: @Tony you can try to change the theme and add new resource as I did basically the issue is coming when this daily update email go to multiple people and then you can try to send any normal markdown email and you will see their theme also changed. i am using laravel 9.31